# Symfony 4, install and use the jsrouting-bundle, route of my controller "does not exist"

Tags: javascript, php, symfony4, fosjsroutingbundle

From Symfony 4, I need to generate dynamicals url path of my controller (controller who need, in the futur, some parameters) from javascript.

After some google searches I found and installed the jsrouting-bundle via a simple `composer require friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle` (I executed the recipe)

I include theses lines in my twig file :

```
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', { callback: 'fos.Router.setData' }) }}"></script>
<script src="build/js/global.js"></script>
```

When I load my page, no javascript errors appeared.

So, I created this very simple symfony controller (for an AJAX call) :

```
/**
 * @Route("/API/test", name="ajax_test")
 */
public function test(){
    $test = [
        'a' => 'foo',
        'b' => 'faa',
    ];
    return new JsonResponse($test);
}
```

And in my custom javascript script (global.js) , I tried this :

alert(Routing.generate('ajax_test'));

But when I load the page, I get this javascript error :

```
Error: The route "ajax_test" does not exist.
```

Why the route is not found ? Where is my mistake ?

Notes :

> in the [friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle documentation](https://github.com/weaverryan/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#step-4-publish-assets/doc/index.md) , from the when I executed the command `bin/console assets:install --symlink web` I get the error `The target directory "web" does not exist.`. So, I executed simply `bin/console assets:install --symlink`
>
> If I go to the "http://localhost/mywebsite/public/js/routing?callback=fos.Router.setData", I get `/**/fos.Router.setData({"base_url":"\/mywebsite\/public","routes":[],"prefix":"","host":"localhost","port":"","scheme":"http"});`

Answer (score 0):

I just add the option "expose" set to true in annotations of my controller like this :

```
/**
 * @Route("/API/test", name="ajax_test", options={"expose"=true})
 */
public function test(){
    $test = [
        'a' => 'foo',
        'b' => 'faa',
    ];
    return new JsonResponse($test);
}
```